# Did Queen Elizabeth attempt to warn her nation that "2017 will be a year of slaughter the likes of which we haven’t seen since World War 2“?

Tags: united-kingdom

According to stories spreading through social media, as well as some webpages (for example this article: [Queen Elizabeth Placed Under ‘House Arrest’ After Christmas Message](http://yournewswire.com/queen-elizabeth-house-arrest-christmas-message/)) that Queen Elizabeth attempted to warn the Britons during her 2016 Christmas Speech that World War 3 is imminent in 2017 because of the machinations of the global elite; and that she hadn't spoken about this before because she was worried for her safety. Allegedly this speech was stopped from being emitted and the Queen was forced to record a new version of the speech and to refrain from telling this message again in the future.

Are there any credible sources to confirm any of the above?

Comment: Well, yournewswire certainly [isn't credible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fake_news_websites#List_of_fake_news_sites) :P

Comment: @Laurel: Probably slightly more credible than a wiki list of "fake news" sites. If you want to follow up the references and post an answer though...

Comment: @Oddthinking It's not just that, they also have their [own tag on Snopes](http://www.snopes.com/tag/yournewswire-com/). Of course, some "fake news" sites will publish real news, so I don't think it's evidence enough for an answer (as this particular claim wasn't one of the ones they busted)...

Comment: The Queen missed church on Christmas Day, so that is apparently evidence she was under house arrest.  She missed it again the following week and I am surprised that they did not have a follow-up article to suggest the issue was getting worse.  The week after that she did go to church (and gave a prize to a local schoolboy) which, if you believe the article, would suggest that she had managed to convince her captors that she could be trusted not to speak openly again.  The alternative might be to think that a 90-year old woman had been ill and then recovered, a clearly less plausible option.

Comment: This can't be true, because a reliable source told me the Queen is Satan and thus wouldn't attempt to warn the public from impending doom. (have fun disproving that). Some claims (like this one or the one about global warning being a chinese hoax) are so ridiculous they need at least some credible evidence before people are required to disprove them.

Comment: We might note that 2017 is half done, with no sign of more than the usual amount of slaughter.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet: If you would like to talk to me in chat, please do so, preferably without the name calling.

Comment: YNW has a 100% Pants On Fire rating from Politifact.

Answer (score -6):

According to [the published transcript of the Queen's speech](https://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2016/dec/25/the-queens-speech-christmas-day-full-transcript-elizabeth), those words are not in it.  I presume you could argue that global elites quickly erased the official record of the speech as they placed her under arrest (which she hasn't been under, as she has definitely been around), but that's highly implausible. I have a number of English friends who would have watched it and I imagine I, like many others, would have heard if her speech included something that extreme.

Comment: The claim, as I understand it, is that she *recorded* a "Year of Slaughter" speech meant for broadcast, but that it was never actually broadcasted; instead, she was made to record a new version which followed the "official" prepared text, and that version was to be broadcasted. So you aren't saying anything inconsistent with the claim.